# How can I rotate an image for a specific time and then stopping it slowly

Tags: javascript, css, image, animation, rotation

I want to rotate an image for a specific time (for example 2 seconds) and with a specific speed and then the rotation gets slower until it stops. 
I am not an expert, I just know how to rotate and image with css, but not with a given speed and and ending.

Comment: Use rotate, transition ease-out for a duration in css with a specific event (focus, hover, active ...)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers :) and thanks for the advice, i will definitley do these things

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Using keyframes is a good way to build an animation. The animation will run for 2 seconds. The ease out property makes the animation end smoothly.
                The forwards property keeps the image from reverting back to its original orientation.

```
<img src="" class="rotation-class" />

.rotation-class {
    width: 200px;
    animation: rotate-animation 2s ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes rotate-animation {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(90deg);}
}
```

To make the animation faster shorten the length of the animation. You can also use percentages in your keyframes animation to further customize your animation.

```
@keyframes rotate-animation {
10% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

20% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

}

Comment: Oh man thank you so much. thats exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Im glad that was what you were looking for :) @Djinii